# PHP, como gravar campo Date em branco no banco de dados?

Tags: php, html

a minha situação, é a seguinte no localhost, o bd, ignora as letras do campo date (dd/mm/aaaa), mas quando subo para o servidor, ele da erro, pois tenho certeza que ele tenta gravar as letras destes campos date.

pois bem, o problema é que eu uso um formulário só para cadastrar e alterar, então loco eu uso o campo value para retornar o valor da tabela quando vou alterar, e por isso não consigo usar o value para colocar por exemplo os valores padrões como 00/00/0000, e eu não consegui outro meio de fazer com que o campo date não PREENCHIDO grave os ZEROS NA tabela ao invés de dar erro.

no banco de dado o campo date, esta para aceitar os valores da seguinte forma 0000-00-00, (as inversões de datas estão funcionando corretamente).

e o campo no form esta assim:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="data_dc" id="data_dc" value="<?=$obreiro_busca['data_dc']?>" style="width:360px">
```

como esta no BD:

```
 `data_dc` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
```

e este é o erro:

Incorrect date value: '' for column 'data_dc' at row 1

eu não consigo fazer com que o campo fique com ZEROS, ao invés de letras.

só não posso usar o campo value.

Comment: Existe um valor especial no banco de dados para valor "não preenchidos", este valor seria `NULL`. Aí é só testar se o campo não está preenchido  no PHP e inserir `NULL` caso seja vazio. Ex.: `$date = $_POST['data_dc'] ?: null;`. É apenas um exemplo, no seu caso seria necessário validar esta data e sanitizar o input o usuário.

Comment: desculpe minha ignorancia, rsrs, então se eu acrecentar esta condição ai no meu codigo, eu terei que verificar antes de gravar certo?  ou só esta condição serve para verificar se esta nulo? se poder dar mais detalhes, agradeço, se precisar eu mostro mais codigo se necessário, vou acrescentar como esta no BD.

Comment: Tu deve altarar a tabela do banco de dados para aceitar que o campo data_dc aceite valores nulos/null. Com a condição que que o @fernandosavio falou tu vai guardar a data que veio do form caso ela tenha sido enviada e se não tiver sido enviada ele vai guardar null. Assim quando não for informado data tu salva null na coluna da data. Outra coisa que poderia ser feito também é alterar para a coluna no banco ter um valor padrão de 0000-00-00 quando não informado, mas não recomendo afinal qual o sentido de salvar 0000-00-00.

Comment: então amigo @fajuchem esta ultima sugestão, até estava dando certo no localhost, mas no servidor não deu, ele continua sem aceitar gravar mesmo com o padrão 0000-00-00.

Comment: Bom, ae é contigo, tu pode começar acessando o banco do servidor e ver como esta a tabela e também pegar a query gerado pelo seu código e tenta inserir manualmente pra ver conseguir mais informações. Não tem muito que de pra te ajuda com as informações atuais.

Comment: por hora obrigado pela ajuda, estou tentando todas estas alternativas, e assim que der, ja posto aqui, a solução